# In golang with database/sql how do I execute from io.Reader?

Tags: go

Specifically, I am using the [MySQL Driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql).

I have a large stream available as an `io.Reader` to execute (it is a mysqldump file, but that shouldn't matter). I can do a `DB.Exec(query string)` or `TX.Exec(query string)`, but how do I get it to read from an `io.Reader`? In many cases, it isn't practical to load the whole thing into a string in memory first.

Essentially, I am looking to do the equivalent of `cat file.sql | mysql -h ...`

Comment: You cannot do this directly. You have to parse the stream into individual queries to use the `sql/database` interface.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I can see if the mysql library has anything to parse the queries, but I doubt it.

Comment: @deitch you know you could also just use `exec.Command("mysq", ...)` (as long as `mysql` installed on the host). And you can also pipe the reader into the `exec.Cmd` if the stream isn't already in the filesystem.

Comment: Yeah, I do. I am trying to avoid the dependency, because I may very well be executing where I cannot control the environment

Comment: I have been reading the original `mysql` source code [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc), to try and understand where it does at parsing; not much luck. Looks like it reads everything? That seems odd.

Comment: You might look at some of the DB schema migration tools in Go for how they handle essentially the same problem. I believe they do indeed parse the input into individual queries, but maybe they have a component you can import, or at least copy-paste into your project. Or maybe you can just use one of those tools directly.

Comment: That is a _really_ good idea, Jonathan. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like lots of `io.ReadAll()`, e.g. https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/blob/master/database/mysql/mysql.go#L338